# how to change legend text font in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i have a bar graph as follows:

```
x=[0.4,0.31,0.21]
y=[0.45,0.38,0.27]
bar(x,y,0.1)
h = bar(x,diag(y),0.1,'stacked');
xlabel('precession')
ylabel('recall')
h_legend=legend('equal to 1 relation','discernible relation','indiscernible relation')
set(h_legend,'FontSize',11);
```

i want to change the font of all the text in this bar graph i.e labels and legend to `Times New Roman` how is this possible any help would be appreciated, i have tried `windowsfonts` but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
set(gca,'FontName','Times New Roman');
```